# "Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipException: Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied" error when running .net maui app in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I created a brand new .NET Maui project in Visual Studio comm. edition 2022 without touching a single line of code, so there is only the standard template Hello World app.

I created a new Android Device (Pixel 5 - API 29 Android 10.0) from the Android Device Manager of Visual Studio.

When I launch the app on the mobile simulator it gives me this error every single time:
"Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipException: Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied"

I uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio as well as the android simulator.
Also I am the admin of my local windows account and I have full privileges both locally and on the network.

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

> "Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipException: Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied"

It's weird. This error usually occurs when building a Xamarin project instead of Maui project.

**Solution 1**

You can try changing the Android version, e.g. Android 12/13, like in this case: [How to resolve this Error XABBA7000: Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipException: Renaming temporary file failed: Permission denied?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1271713/how-to-resolve-this-error-xabba7000-xamarin-tools).

**Solution 2**

Close your project (visual studio), go to your project folder, and delete bin & obj. Then reopen visual studion(project) and run it.